# Get Tensorboard scalars regexp filter rememberd

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

There is quite a lot of plots shown in the scalars tab by default, while I only want to see some of them. The regular expression filter in the scalars tab allows to select, which of the variables gets plotted bellow, however, it must be entered again each time I visit the Tensorboard page.

Is it possible to get the entered regular expression remembered between individual visits of the Tensorboard page? Or is it possible to write the expression as URL parameter so I could add the address including the filter in the browser bookmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a future release of TensorBoard, you will be able to use the `tagFilter` GET parameter of the URL to specify the tag filter. Furthermore, your previous `tagFilter` will be remembered by the browser (stored within `localStorage`) and re-populated within the regex input field upon revisiting TensorBoard.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/787

To try out this feature today, install TensorBoard nightly (via `pip install tb-nightly`), which lets you use TensorBoard's latest features at the expense of using its bleeding edge version.

Comment: Good news! Is the nightly version compatible with the stable version of the TensorFlow? Checking `pip freeze`, I have `tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0` and
`tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0rc3`, don't remember installing TensorBoard separately, likely it came as dependency of TensorFlow.